# node.js deployment failing on railway Error: Docker build failed

Tags: node.js, npm, deployment, npm-install, railway

## [Region: us-west1]

## Using Nixpacks

context: 95edb029943be73caab8691374c63474

╔════════ Nixpacks v1.21.2 ═══════╗
║ setup      │ nodejs_18, npm-9_x ║
║─────────────────────────────────║
║ install    │ npm i              ║
║─────────────────────────────────║
║ build      │ npm run build      ║
║─────────────────────────────────║
║ start      │ npm run start      ║
╚═════════════════════════════════╝

````
#1 [internal] load build definition from Dockerfile
#1 transferring dockerfile: 5.62kB done
#1 DONE 0.0s

#2 [internal] load metadata for ghcr.io/railwayapp/nixpacks:ubuntu-1707782610

#2 DONE 0.2s


#3 [stage-0 1/8] FROM ghcr.io/railwayapp/nixpacks:ubuntu-1707782610@sha256:8f4b0fd95dc3311cf9a59f236d8d7d7f956fe21a2a1d64b53c82f12c4e859f09
#3 DONE 0.0s

#4 [internal] load .dockerignore
#4 transferring context: 2B done
#4 DONE 0.0s

#5 [internal] load build context

#5 transferring context: 631.34kB 0.1s done
#5 DONE 0.1s

#6 [stage-0 2/8] WORKDIR /app/
#6 CACHED

#7 [stage-0  3/10] COPY .nixpacks/nixpkgs-bf744fe90419885eefced41b3e5ae442d732712d.nix .nixpacks/nixpkgs-bf744fe90419885eefced41b3e5ae442d732712d.nix
#7 CACHED

#8 [stage-0  4/10] RUN nix-env -if .nixpacks/nixpkgs-bf744fe90419885eefced41b3e5ae442d732712d.nix && nix-collect-garbage -d
#8 CACHED

#9 [stage-0  5/10] COPY . /app/.
#9 DONE 0.1s


#10 [stage-0  6/10] RUN --mount=type=cache,id=s/8dc0bc9f-687f-4869-a86d-555415a3428f-/root/npm,target=/root/.npm npm i

#10 0.646 npm
WARN config production Use `--omit=dev` instead.

#10 ...

#6 [stage-0 2/8] WORKDIR /app/
#6 CACHED


#10 [stage-0  6/10] RUN --mount=type=cache,id=s/8dc0bc9f-687f-4869-a86d-555415a3428f-/root/npm,target=/root/.npm npm i

#10 28.43 npm WARN deprecated fastify-multipart@5.4.0: Please use @fastify/multipart@6.0.0 instead

#10 28.82 npm WARN deprecated har-validator@5.1.5: this library is no longer supported

#10 29.24 npm WARN deprecated circular-json@0.5.9: CircularJSON is in maintenance only, flatted is its successor.

#10 29.54 npm WARN deprecated alphanumeric@1.1.3: this package has been deprecated

#10 29.59 npm WARN deprecated statsd-client@0.4.7: Package no longer supported. Contact Support at https://www.npmjs.com/support for more info.

#10 29.74 npm WARN deprecated uuid@3.4.0: Please upgrade  to version 7 or higher.  Older versions may use Math.random() in certain circumstances, which is known to be problematic.  See https://v8.dev/blog/math-random for details.

#10 29.87 npm WARN deprecated mkdirp@0.5.1: Legacy versions of mkdirp are no longer supported. Please update to mkdirp 1.x. (Note that the API surface has changed to use Promises in 1.x.)

#10 29.95 npm WARN deprecated request@2.88.2: request has been deprecated, see https://github.com/request/request/issues/3142

#10 30.16 npm WARN deprecated connect@2.30.2: connect 2.x series is deprecated

#10 52.35 npm ERR! code 1

#10 52.35 npm ERR! path /app/node_modules/node-rdkafka
#10 52.35 npm ERR! command failed
#10 52.35 npm ERR! command sh -c node-gyp rebuild
#10 52.35 npm ERR! gyp info it worked if it ends with ok
#10 52.35 npm ERR! gyp info using node-gyp@9.4.0
#10 52.35 npm ERR! gyp info using node@18.18.2 | linux | x64
#10 52.35 npm ERR! gyp ERR! find Python
#10 52.35 npm ERR! gyp ERR! find Python Python is not set from command line or npm configuration
#10 52.35 npm ERR! gyp ERR! find Python Python is not set from environment variable PYTHON

#10 52.35 npm ERR! gyp ERR! find Python checking if "python3" can be used
#10 52.35 npm ERR! gyp ERR! find Python - "python3" is not in PATH or produced an error
#10 52.35 npm ERR! gyp ERR! find Python checking if "python" can be used
#10 52.35 npm ERR! gyp ERR! find Python - "python" is not in PATH or produced an error
#10 52.35 npm ERR! gyp ERR! find Python
#10 52.35 npm ERR! gyp ERR! find Python **********************************************************
#10 52.35 npm ERR! gyp ERR! find Python You need to install the latest version of Python.
#10 52.35 npm ERR! gyp ERR! find Python Node-gyp should be able to find and use Python. If not,
#10 52.35 npm ERR! gyp ERR! find Python you can try one of the following options:
#10 52.35 npm ERR! gyp ERR! find Python - Use the switch --python="/path/to/pythonexecutable"
#10 52.35 npm ERR! gyp ERR! find Python   (accepted by both node-gyp and npm)
#10 52.35 npm ERR! gyp ERR! find Python - Set the environment variable PYTHON
#10 52.35 npm ERR! gyp ERR! find Python - Set the npm configuration variable python:
#10 52.35 npm ERR! gyp ERR! find Python   npm config set python "/path/to/pythonexecutable"
#10 52.35 npm ERR! gyp ERR! find Python For more information consult the documentation at:
#10 52.35 npm ERR! gyp ERR! find Python https://github.com/nodejs/node-gyp#installation
#10 52.35 npm ERR! gyp ERR! find Python **********************************************************
#10 52.35 npm ERR! gyp ERR! find Python
#10 52.35 npm ERR! gyp ERR! configure error
#10 52.35 npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack Error: Could not find any Python installation to use
#10 52.35 npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at PythonFinder.fail (/nix/store/5l687mklyr9rhhbvvpvi93zv0zbbi4vg-nodejs-18.18.2/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/lib/find-python.js:330:47)
#10 52.35 npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at PythonFinder.runChecks (/nix/store/5l687mklyr9rhhbvvpvi93zv0zbbi4vg-nodejs-18.18.2/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/lib/find-python.js:159:21)
#10 52.35 npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at PythonFinder.<anonymous> (/nix/store/5l687mklyr9rhhbvvpvi93zv0zbbi4vg-nodejs-18.18.2/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/lib/find-python.js:202:16)
#10 52.35 npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at PythonFinder.execFileCallback (/nix/store/5l687mklyr9rhhbvvpvi93zv0zbbi4vg-nodejs-18.18.2/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/lib/find-python.js:294:16)
#10 52.35 npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at exithandler (node:child_process:430:5)
#10 52.35 npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.errorhandler (node:child_process:442:5)
#10 52.35 npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (node:events:517:28)
#10 52.35 npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess._handle.onexit (node:internal/child_process:290:12)
#10 52.35 npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at onErrorNT (node:internal/child_process:477:16)
#10 52.35 npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:82:21)
#10 52.35 npm ERR! gyp ERR! System Linux 5.10.0-28-cloud-amd64
#10 52.35 npm ERR! gyp ERR! command "/nix/store/5l687mklyr9rhhbvvpvi93zv0zbbi4vg-nodejs-18.18.2/bin/node" "/nix/store/5l687mklyr9rhhbvvpvi93zv0zbbi4vg-nodejs-18.18.2/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js" "rebuild"
#10 52.35 npm ERR! gyp ERR! cwd /app/node_modules/node-rdkafka
#10 52.35 npm ERR! gyp ERR! node -v v18.18.2
#10 52.35 npm ERR! gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v9.4.0
#10 52.35 npm ERR! gyp ERR! not ok
#10 52.36
#10 52.36 npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in: /root/.npm/_logs/2024-03-24T19_15_14_836Z-debug-0.log

#10 ERROR: process "/bin/bash -ol pipefail -c npm i" did not complete successfully: exit code: 1

-----
> [stage-0  6/10] RUN --mount=type=cache,id=s/8dc0bc9f-687f-4869-a86d-555415a3428f-/root/npm,target=/root/.npm npm i:
52.35 npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at onErrorNT (node:internal/child_process:477:16)
52.35 npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:82:21)
52.35 npm ERR! gyp ERR! System Linux 5.10.0-28-cloud-amd64
52.35 npm ERR! gyp ERR! command "/nix/store/5l687mklyr9rhhbvvpvi93zv0zbbi4vg-nodejs-18.18.2/bin/node" "/nix/store/5l687mklyr9rhhbvvpvi93zv0zbbi4vg-nodejs-18.18.2/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js" "rebuild"
52.35 npm ERR! gyp ERR! cwd /app/node_modules/node-rdkafka
52.35 npm ERR! gyp ERR! node -v v18.18.2
52.35 npm ERR! gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v9.4.0
52.35 npm ERR! gyp ERR! not ok
52.36
52.36 npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in: /root/.npm/_logs/2024-03-24T19_15_14_836Z-debug-0.log
-----

Dockerfile:20
-------------------
18 |     ENV NIXPACKS_PATH /app/node_modules/.bin:$NIXPACKS_PATH
19 |     COPY . /app/.
20 | >>> RUN --mount=type=cache,id=s/8dc0bc9f-687f-4869-a86d-555415a3428f-/root/npm,target=/root/.npm npm i
21 |
22 |     # build phase
-------------------
ERROR: failed to solve: process "/bin/bash -ol pipefail -c npm i" did not complete successfully: exit code: 1

Error: Docker build failed```

does any one have any idea why this deployment is failing, plus i'm so confused why i am seeing python on the log. can
````